# If-else statement inside apply function R

Tags: r, apply

I am writing an apply function in R to search a table and return all the instances that TRUE occurs, and I have written the following code but it keeps giving me errors, and I am not sure why. Any help is appreciated.

```
xsum = apply(genomeTable, 1, function(i) {

    if (i) < q.start | if (i) > q.end{
      return FALSE

    } else{
      return TRUE
    }
  })

sum(xsum)
```

Comment: Try `if (i < q.start) | if (i > q.end) {...` Also maybe this can be solved in a simpler way if you can give a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the quick answer! I tried the above but it didn't solve the errors I keep getting which are Error: unexpected '}' in "  }" or the like.

Comment: It is difficult to help without any data. Can you add a reproducible example ?

Comment: I'm really new to programming so I am not completely sure what a reproducible example means, but I am trying to find overlapping regions in a genome, which is why I have the table genomeTable that I loaded from the human genome file, and my variables are:                                                                                          
 genome <- "gencode.v31.annotation.gff3.gz"                                     
 genomeTable <- read.table(genome, header = F, sep = "\t", nrows = 1000)       
chr = 10
q.start = 10000
q.end = 20000

Answer (score 4):

Your `if` statement is duplicated. You only need one `if` for the condition. Parenthesis need to wrap the whole condition. Try this:

```
xsum = apply(genomeTable, 1, function(i) {
  if (i < q.start | i > q.end) {
    return(FALSE)
  } else {
    return(TRUE)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
xsum = apply(genomeTable, 1, function(i) ifelse ((i < q.sta | i > q.end), FALSE, TRUE))
```

It does not work, please provide some data.